# Django render() in 2.X

Tags: django, django-views, render

I ran into this problem while trying to capture POST data.

In Django 1.X, I structured my views like this:

```
def view_name(request, template_name='template.html'):
     variable1 = data
     variable2 = moreData         

     return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now, I see that render_to_response() has been deprecated, but I'm unsure how to port the code with all of the locals() calls.

Do I have to convert all of my views by building a dict with all desired variables?

Is there another way to port this to keep the locals() incorporation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call this with:

```
def view_name(request, template_name='template.html'):
     variable1 = data
     variable2 = moreData

     # …
     return render(request, template_name, locals())
```

That being said, please do *not* use `locals()`. It makes it very unclear what exactly you pass to the template. Furthermore you often will pass more to the template than you want to. Finally most IDEs will say a variable is not used, and thus you might remove it, but it is in fact used in the template.